# Deactivate start of app

Tags: applications

I have an app called "podcast" on my phone. unfortunately, when i try to open it, android closes the app because "it slows down my device" and gives me this notification: "Podcast was closed. to use it again, deactivate automatic start of the app".

I downloaded autorun manager to do this task, but it doesn't seem to work with my phone because it's unrooted and has a android-version which is too new.

what can i do to get my app running again?

I think it's an absolute joke that my phone deactivates an app automatically and i have to put so much effort into finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases a startup manager does not require root to disable an app from startup unless the app is a system application. I am not too sure as to why autorun manager is requiring root, but I would suggest installing a different app to manage startup apps.
In the past I have used Startup Manager to do this.
[Try this app and see if it fixes your issue.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager)